# Adjust CircularProgressIndicator size inside Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I trying to add a `CircularProgressIndicator` in the center of `Card`. I wrapping `CircularProgressIndicator` in `Container` so I can smaller it, but it doesn't work.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Card(
                        elevation: 2,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                            height: 10, child: CircularProgressIndicator()))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container will expand if the parent constrains are stretched. That's what's happening. To center the ProgressIndicator you should use the center widget

```
child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

 @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Padding(

                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),

                child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Card(
                        elevation: 2,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator()))));}}
```